# Finding text files with less than 2000 rows and deleting them

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have A LOT of text files, with just one column.

Some text file have 2000 lines (consisting of numbers), and some others have less than 2000 lines (also consisting only of numbers).

I want to delete all the textiles with less than 2000 lines in them.

EXTRA INFO

The files that have less than 2000 lines, are not empty they all have line breaks till row 2000. Plus my files have some complicated names like: Nameofpop_chr1_window1.txt

I tried using awk to first count the lines of my text file, but because there are line breaks for every file I get the same result, 2000 for every file.

```
awk 'END { print NR }' Nameofpop_chr1_window1.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk to count non-empty lines:

```
awk 'NF{i++} END { print i }' Nameofpop_chr1_window1.txt
```

OR this awk to count only those lines that have **only numbers**

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+$/ {i++} END { print i }' Nameofpop_chr1_window1.txt
```

To **delete all files with less than 2000 lines with numbers** use this awk:

```
for f in f*; do
    [[ -n $(awk '/^[[:digit:]]+$/{i++} END {if (i<2000) print FILENAME}' "$f") ]] && rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But how can I save all the files that had more than 2000 lines with numbers?

Comment: see updated code to delete all files with less than 2000 lines with numbers.

Comment: All the files were deleted including those with 2000 lines in them

Comment: I had tested this before posting. Can you show your code in your question.

Comment: Can you try this script: http://pastebin.com/YYU0MArm and see what it prints? (I just replaced `rm` with `echo rm`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47510/discussion-between-jm88-and-anubhava)

Comment: @jaypalsingh: lol :) my buddy, where were you, that is hilarious. It seems OP had `\r` in the end and we came up with little different awk command on cha session but it shouldn't have deleted all files

Comment: @jaypalsingh: I do sleep but sleep hours are different due to different timezones of my work and my home now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `expr $(cat filename|sort|uniq|wc -l) - 1` or `cat filename|grep -v '^$'|wc -l` it will give you the number of lines per file and based on that you decidewhat to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash:

```
for f in $files; do
    n=0
    while read line; do
        [[ -n $line ]] && ((n++))
    done < $f
    [ $n -lt 2000 ] && rm $f
done
```